# simple MySQL query sorting date and then group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I worked with MySQL years ago and I'm not best with it yet.
The query I need is for my messenger webapp, grouping conversations between two people and show only the newest message like a overview (f.e. In facebook messenger).
I tested a lot of queries (subquery, subselect, max(added)) but haven't succeeded, I hope you can help me.

That's the database:

[image: database]

A chat between two people is the conversation and all messages in this chat have the same `conversation_id`. If a new chat starts between two other people, a new `conversation_id` will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM messages where conversation_id=your_id ORDER BY added;
```

Let me know if you have problem?

Comment: Thank you @Sadikhasan but this doesnt work because one conversation_id is for one chat between two partners but normaly you have more conversations from one person, so i thought maybe group by conservation_id shows only one message from the conservation. This message is only the first one but i need the newest one, hope you understand ;)

Comment: What you want? all conversation of each user?

Comment: Only the newest message (sort by added) from each conversation where receiver=$personLoggedIn or sender=$personLoggedIn